# How to change the value of a $scope.variable in a controller from a directive in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am very new to the concepts of angularJS. The problem I am facing is `I have declared a variable $scope.myVariable = true` in my `controller`. I need to toggle the the value of `$scope.myVariable` from the `directive`. Is it possible to do that.. if yes how??
Please help..

Comment: the code will help. what do you mean in the `directive`? in the html? in the `link` function? 
In the meantime, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the reference of "myVariable" from your main controller to the directive like this :

//index.html

```
<my-directive myvar="myVariable"></my-directive>
```

//myDirective.js

```
app.directive('myDirective', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E", 
        require: 'myvar',
        scope: {
            myvar:"=" //"=" mean, you can set the variable (your toggle function needs that)
        },
        templateUrl: "./directives/myDirective/myDirectiveView.html",
        controller: "myDirectiveController as myDirectiveCtrl"
    }
}]);
```

With this solution, myvar in the directive contains the reference to myVariable of the main controller and you can use it with $scope.myvar in the directive.

EDIT : 
for example, if you have a list for object contains src and compression var like this :

{ src:"path/to/img", compressed:false}

```
<div ng-repeat="imgObj in imgObjList">
    <my-directive myvar="imgObj"></my-directive>
</div>
```

In the my-directive view :

```
<img ng-src="myvar.src" ng-show="myvar.compressed == true"/>
```

In your my-directive Controller :

you can set myvar.compressed to true when encoding is finished

Comment: okay the situation is something like this.. I am using a image directive which accepts a list of images for compression and display in the view. But meanwhile the compression takes place I need to display a loading effect.
The Idea what I was thinking is use a controller variable  and pass it to the directive and as my directive loops over the list of images I will toggle the controller variable which I am planning to use in my html file using ng-if/ng-show to display a `<div` as required. Is my way correct to achieve this functionality??

Comment: You want display each image one by one or just print the loading during the compression and display all images at the end ?

Comment: one by one as the image loads.

Comment: I see the solution like this : You have the ng-repeat in your "list of images" directive who call your "single image" directive. you can create a list of object like : { src:"", compressed:false} and in you ng-repeat, you pass the complet object to you single image directive, i write the code in my anwser (it will be more clear)

Answer (score 0):

From a directive, you can access the scope through the link function:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    controller: 'MyController',
    templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.name = 'Jeff';
    }
  };
});
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Angularjs Directive, you can use 3 methods of it's scope

**1) true (inherit)**

**2) false (not inherit)**

**3) {} (Isolated)**

if you use **1) method**, you **have to work with it's parent scope, because that variable is in parent scope**

if you use **2) method** you don't have to do anything else.You are **working with current scope**

if you want more with examples here is a cool link
http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/bind-variable-inside-angularjs-directive-isolated-scope.html